# Questions about a Dell Dimension 2400

Tags: drivers, dell

I have recently acquired a Dimension 2400. I have upgraded it to 1 GB of RAM in hopes to install ubuntu. I have installed windows 7 in the meantime, i had some troubles with drivers but finally got it working. I was fluffing about the internet and found some drivers that may or may not work.

My question is: What Ubuntu version should i get? and What should i do to install these drivers: [link](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/8203/Intel-Graphics-Driver-Linux-IntelGraphics-060704-tar-gz-)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try out the latest version of Ubuntu, **15.04 Vivid Vervet** will be your choice.

However, it will reach its [end-of-life](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life) in January 2016.

If you want to use a more long-lasting version, you can use **14.04.1 Trusty Tahr LTS**. It will be supported until April 2019 (for 14.04.2, 14.04.3, they are Trusty Tahr as well, but the kernel they use will be supported till August 2016, which means that you will be facing a major kernel upgrade by that time)

For the driver stuff, most of the drivers (e.g. Intel graphic driver) are included in the kernel, except those proprietary drivers, if everything works fine with just Ubuntu installed, then you don't need that driver pack. As this driver pack was published in 12/17/2004, I think it's already available in the kernel.